# Wi-Fi connected but can't go to any site

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet, ping

My Windows 7 laptop can connect to our Wi-Fi signal, I can sign in on Yahoo! Messenger, but I can't go to any site. I can access the Net on other devices. The issue started a few weeks ago, so I've been troubleshooting since then in vain. There's no virus, and I already used System Restore. In Wireless Network Connection Status, the received activity is greater than the sent activity. I turned off Windows Firewall and still no Net access.

My ping tests:

[image: ping]

How do I fix this?

Comment: what is 192.168.1.101 and what is 192.168.1.103 and what is 192.168.1.1? Do ipconfig /all and paste the result here

Comment: Have you tried another browser?

Comment: On Chrome, no Net access whatsoever. On Internet Explorer, it is very slow.

Comment: could you try running a traceroute out to a couple of sites and five us the output?

Comment: result of ipconfig /all: [pic 1](http://i.imgur.com/Om3Hs.jpg)  [pic 2](http://i.imgur.com/3o64U.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It loks like your pinging your own router or gateway and also your loopback
connection.

I would run ipconfig /flushdns
first. Then ipconfig /all

Change the ADSL filter. Check that all cable connections to the router are secure.

Using another clean computer get the latest firmware update for your router.
Save to a handy USB drive or CD.

Then disconnect the ADSL cable from the router temporarily and any extra dvices that you may have connected to it.

Connect your computer with a ethernet cable direct to the router.

Launch your browser and login into the administration server of the router.
To login you will have to follow the instructions given by the manufacturer
of your router. Check the leaflet that came with it, and or the makers website.
You can also check the bottom or back of the router. Sometimes the password is there.
You also will find a Reset button. Pressing it for a number of seconds (may be 30) will reset the routers password to the factory default.

Check all that all settings are correct. (It may be a good idea to set the DNS servers to
OpenDNS servers).

If you downloaded an image to update your router, you can proceed to update.
You may have to login in and out a couple of times, but it won't take long.

Set a new strong password for the administrator of the router.

Set the encription protocol of the router to the strongest possible available to you.
If possible set it to WPA2. Set a new passfrase or password for the encription or your connection key. Check wwww.grc.com for their free, indivual, unique password service.
You could save it to a usb drive, for later use (copy and paste). Jus do not mislay the drive and keep it safe and out of sight.

When finished, reconnect the ADSL cable to the router and any other connections that you
undid.
Now you are ready to go as you normally do.

Best of luck